# Como faço para enviar um campo apenas por ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

No momento estou enviando o formulário inteiro, preciso enviar apenas um campo do html por ajax, o IdAparelho é dinâmico e vem do banco de dados segue o meu codigo ajax e o campo que preciso enviar:

AJAX

```
$(function () {    
        $("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var FormData = $("#visualizarAparelhos").serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST", 
              url: "administrador.php",
              data: FormData
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        return false;
        alert("Não enviou!!!");
        }); 
    });
```

CAMPO PARA SER ENVIADO :

```
 print "<td><button id='IdAparelho' value='".$id."' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalVisualizarComponentes'>".$id."</button></td>";
```

Comment: Roberto, esse "id" que você está usando, está sendo o mesmo para cada linha ? tipo, você tem vários buttons com id='IdAparelho' e só muda o value ?

Comment: Não, esse id é dinâmico, ele vem do banco de dados, eu só quero pegar o value do botão que eu apertar.

Comment: certo, então não terá outro elemento com o mesmo `id ='IdAparelho'` ? Pergunto isso pois é um erro comum criar várias linhas alterando somente o valor e mantendo todos os id iguais (o que não funciona, pois os ids precisam ser únicos)

Comment: Verdade Lucas, eu não tinha pensado nisso, entendi a sua lógica, vou arrumar essa questão também, vou fazer IdAparelho+$Id

Comment: @RobertoAlbino viu minha resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode obter o valor da entrada com [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var idAparelho = $("#IdAparelho").val();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST", 
              url: "administrador.php",
              data: idAparelho 
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        return false;
        alert("Não enviou!!!");
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Alterei o meu ajax com o seu código, e agora está retornado o seguinte erro : jquery.min.js:5 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Loop infinito, jovem.

Comment: Não seria `data: "idAparelho=" + idAparelho`?

Comment: "preciso enviar apenas um campo do html por ajax", eu entendi que ele quer enviar somente um campo, e é um post, não entendo muito de PHP, mas geralmente é usado parâmetro com get.

Comment: Mas o `.val` não envia o "campo" ele envia o valor do campo :/

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas por quê seria interessante enviar o campo e o valor, se ele quiser enviar somente um campo?

Comment: Para pegar um valor no POST é necessário uma key e um valor, no caso você só está enviado o valor, foi isso o que eu quis dizer, teu exemplo esta fazendo apenas o envio do valor e não tem uma chave associativa para indentificar dentro do `$_POST`. Na verdade no seu exemplo o valor vira uma chave, o que torna mais dificil de obter

Answer (score 0):

Já que está usando `serialize`, você pode concatenar as variáveis assim:

```
FormData + "&idAparelho=" + idAparelho
```

Um exemplo:

```
$(function () {    
    $("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var FormData = $("#visualizarAparelhos").serialize();
        var idAparelho = $("#IdAparelho").val();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "administrador.php",
          data: FormData + "&idAparelho=" + idAparelho
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Removi o `alert("Não enviou!!!");`, pois ele não fazia sentido após o `return false;`, já que tudo que vem depois de `return ;` nunca será executado.

Answer (score 0):

Como você quer enviar somente o ID do aparelho, o certo seria:

```
$("#visualizarAparelhos").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          url: "administrador.php",
          data: {idAparelho: $("#IdAparelho").val()}
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```